# How can I use a list to write into an Excel cell range using openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, iteration, openpyxl

I currently have a simple list containing integers: `amounts = [5, 10, 15]`. I would like to write these values into Excel cells, without having to type out statements for each element. At the moment, I have the following code which writes all elements of the list, but without iteration and instead with individual statements.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
amounts = [5, 10, 15]
book = load_workbook("output.xlsx")
sheet = book.active

sheet["A2"] = amounts[0]
sheet["B2"] = amounts[1]
sheet["C2"] = amounts[2]

print ("done")
book.save("output.xlsx")
```

I understand I can define a cell range by doing this; `cells = sheet["A2":"C2"]`. How can I use `cells` and `amounts` together to iterate with each other, so that I can assign `amounts[0]` to `A2`, `amounts[1]` to `B2`, and so on. This list is bigger in reality, just made it smaller for question's sake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set value into cell using method *cell*

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

amounts = [5, 10, 15]
book = Workbook()
sheet = book.active

row = 2
for i, value in enumerate(amounts):
    sheet.cell(column=i+1, row=row, value=value)

print("done")
book.save("output.xlsx")
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I did actually discover my own solution too. Both solutions work well. Thanks.